# Symmetric difference in ARM

Tags: arm

I am trying to make a program on ARM that finds the symmetric difference between two sets and stores it in a separate set and I am not sure what I am doing wrong, can somebody help?
Here is what I have:

```
start

    LDR R0, = ASize     ;load number of elements in A
    LDR R0, [R0]        
    LDR R1, = BSize     ;load number of elements in B
    LDR R1, [R1]        
    LDR R2, = CSize     ;load number of elements in C
    LDR R2, [R2]        
    LDR R3, = AElems    ;load elements in A
    LDR R4, = BElems    ;load elements in B
    LDR R5, = CElems    ;load elements in C
    LDR R8, = '?'

while

    CMP R0,#0
    BEQ endwh

while2

    CMP R1,#0
    BEQ endwh   
    LDR R6, [R3]
    LDR R7, [R4]
    CMP R6,R7
    BEQ endwh
    STR R7, [R5]
    ADD R2,R2,#1
    ADD R4,R4,#4
    STR R8, [R4]
    SUB R1,R1,#1

    B   while
    STR R6, [R5]    
    ADD R2,R2,#1
    STR R8, [R3]
    SUB R0,R0,#1
    ADD R3,R3,#4
    B   while2

endwh

stop    B   stop
```

Comment: Do you assume that the 'A' and 'B' arrays are ordered?  I think your 2nd `beq endwh` should reload 'r1==BSize' and 'r4' as 'BElems' to restart for the next element.  Also, if 'CMP R6,R7' is true, it just mean to discard the value (logic *and*) of the result set 'C', not end the algorithm.  It would be helpful to comment your code and use `.set name rN` to give your register more meaningful names.  Can you write either 'C' code or a flow chart, etc of what you want to happen?  You need a label after `b while`; it is currently dead code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out thanks for the help!
here is the solution I came up with

```
start
   LDR R0, = ASize
   LDR R0, [R0]
   LDR R1, = BSize
   LDR R1, [R1]
   LDR R2, = CSize
   LDR R2, [R2]
   LDR R3, = AElems
   LDR R4, = BElems
   LDR R5, = CElems
   LDR R8, = '?'

while
  CMP R0,#0
  BEQ endwh1
  LDR R6, [R3]
  LDR R7, [R4]
  CMP R6,R7
  BNE endwh2
  STR R8, [R3]
  STR R8, [R4]
  ADD R3,R3,#4
  SUB R0,R0,#1
  B   while
endwh2
  CMP R1,#0
  BEQ endwh3
  ADD R4,R4,#4
  SUB R1,R1,#1 
  B     while
endwh3
  STR R6,   [R5]
  ADD R5,R5,#4
  ADD R2,R2,#1
  ADD R3,R3,#4
  SUB R0,R0,#1
  LDR R4, = BElems
  LDR R1, = BSize
  LDR R1, [R1]
  B   while
endwh1
while2
  CMP R1,#0
  BEQ endwh
  LDR R7, [R4]
  CMP R7,#'?'
  BEQ endwh4
  STR R7, [R5]
  ADD R2,R2,#1
  ADD R5,R5,#4
  ADD R4,R4,#4
  SUB R1,R1,#1
  B   while2
endwh4
  ADD R4,R4,#4
  SUB R1,R1,#1
  B     while2
endwh
stop  B   stop
```